# Remove index.php from URL Codeigniter 1.7.2

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have moved my codeigniter project and all the related databases from old server (Centos 5.11) to new server (Centos 6.7). In the old server, the task of removing the index.php from URL was already handled with the help of the .htacess files and other changes. I have moved the entire project on the new server without making any changes. When I visit the main page of the project i.e. the login page it works fine and gets displayed without any issue. But the moment I login, I get a 404 error page. But when I add index.php fragment at the required place then it works! Did moving the project to latest server version cause a problem?

Comment: Show your htaccess. We can't help with only text..

Comment: Codeigniter 1.7.2. is very out dated now they are up to 3.0.6 version http://www.codeigniter.com/download

Comment: Yes I know! But we are not considering the option for upgrading

Answer (score 0):

```
 RewriteEngine On
 Options All

 #php_flag display_errors Off
 #php_value error_reporting 1
 #php_value post_max_size 8M
 #php_value upload_max_filesize 8M
 #php_value memory_limit 150M
 # These settings when uncommented, giving 500 Internal Server Error on 
 # the new server http://119.18.48.12

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

#RewriteRule ^/(.*).php         /uat/index.php/$1.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*).php          index.php/$1.php [L,NC]

#Local Server Setting
#RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)            administration.php/$1 [L,NC]
#LIVE Server setting
RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)         /uat/administration.php/$1 [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

#Local Server Setting
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$             index.php/$1 [L]
#LIVE Server setting
RewriteRule ^(.*)$          /uat/index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Remove /uat from the path.

Comment: Did that. Now it says No input file specified!

Comment: I am using IP address instead of domain name to access the project on new server. Is that a case of concern?

Answer (score 0):

```
Options -Indexes 
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA] 
        #RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?localhost [NC] 
        #RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?localhost.*$ [NC] 
        #RewriteRule \.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png)$ - [F]
</IfModule>  
#Gzip
<ifmodule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/text text/html text/plain text/xml text/css application/x-javascript application/javascript text/javascript
</ifmodule>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header add Cache-Control:  "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate"
Header unset Pragma
FileETag None
Header unset ETag
</IfModule>
#End Gzip
# BEGIN Expire headers  
<ifModule mod_expires.c>  
    ExpiresActive On  
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 5 seconds"  
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 2592000 seconds"  
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 2592000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 2592000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 2592000 seconds"  
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 2592000 seconds"  
    ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 600 seconds"  
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 604800 seconds"  
    ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 216000 seconds"  
    ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 2592000 seconds"  
    ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 216000 seconds"  
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 216000 seconds"  
    ExpiresByType application/xhtml+xml "access plus 600 seconds"  
</ifModule>
```